# TSQL Query 12 months of Data - Include Months without records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a 12 month grid view of all questions that were submitting for each month in that 12 month period.

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(h.metaInsert) [Year], 
    MONTH(h.metaInsert) [Month], 
    DATENAME(MONTH,h.metaInsert) [Month Name], 
    COUNT(1) [Total Documents]
FROM 
    Document_Count_History AS h
WHERE 
    YEAR(h.metaInsert) = 2017
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(h.metaInsert), MONTH(h.metaInsert), DATENAME(MONTH, h.metaInsert)
ORDER BY 
    1, 2
```

This returns the data perfectly for the months that have it, but I get no data returned for those with 0 records for that specific month.

My goal is to see all 12 months along with the count of documents. If there are no documents, it will simply be a 0 for that month but it will be included in the result set.

How can I take what I have and apply the missing months?

Comment: You need a `LEFT JOIN` and a list of months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this to generate the sequence of months for your query:

```
declare @StartDate     date = '20170101'
       ,@NumberOfYears int  = 1;

;with Months as (
select top (12*@NumberOfYears) 
    [Month] = dateadd(Month, row_number() over (order by number) -1, @StartDate)
   , NextMonth = dateadd(Month, row_number() over (order by number), @StartDate)
  from master.dbo.spt_values
)

select 
    year(m.Month) [Year], 
    Month(m.Month) [Month], 
    datename(Month,m.Month) [Month Name], 
    count(h.*) [Total Documents]

from Months as m
  left join Document_Count_History AS h
    on h.metaInsert >= m.Month
   and h.metaInsert < m.NextMonth
--where h.metaInsert >= '20170101'
group by m.Month
order by m.Month
```

Although you may want to consider adding a Calendar table, or Date Dimension.

Calendar and Numbers table references:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in SQL Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

An example months table:

```
create table dbo.Months(
    MonthStart date not null primary key
  , NextMonthStart date not null
  , [Year] smallint not null
  , [Month] tinyint not null
  , [MonthName] varchar(16) not null
);

declare @StartDate     date = '20100101'
       ,@NumberOfYears int  = 30;

insert dbo.Months(MonthStart,NextMonthStart,[Year],[Month])
  select top (12*@NumberOfYears) 
    [MonthStart] = dateadd(month, row_number() over (order by number) -1, @StartDate)
    , NextMonthStart = dateadd(month, row_number() over (order by number), @StartDate)
    , [year] = year(dateadd(month, row_number() over (order by number) -1, @StartDate))
    , [Month] = Month(dateadd(month, row_number() over (order by number) -1, @StartDate))
    , MonthName =  datename(Month,dateadd(month, row_number() over (order by number) -1, @StartDate))
  from master.dbo.spt_values;
```

and your query would simplify to:

```
select 
    m.[Year], 
    m.[Month], 
    m.[MonthName], 
    count(h.*) [Total Documents]
from Months as m
  left join Document_Count_History AS h
    on h.metaInsert >= m.MonthStart
   and h.metaInsert < m.NextMonthStart
where m.Year = 2017
group by m.Month, m.Year, m.MonthName
order by m.MonthStart
```

Comment: Testing this now - instead of providing a start date, can I just pass a year? I will only ever need to see one year at a time so I think that would clean up with `startDate` and `numberOfYears` logic

Comment: You could further simplify the logic with a Months table instead of generating it every time you needed it. @SBB

Comment: I found a calendar table we are using but it doesn't contain a next month start. Trying to add this to my join: ` and h.metaInsert < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, h.metaInsert)`. I think this syntax is off a bit though cause my document numbers are wrong. I have the year, month, and month name showing correctly though.

Comment: @SBB if your calendar is by individual date, then it would be `on h.metaInsert >= c.Date
   and h.metaInsert < dateadd(day,1,c.Date)`, and the `group by` takes care off aggregating it to year and month. Unless `h.metaInsert` is a `date` type and then you could use `h.metaInsert = c.Date`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a date dimension.  Specifically, you need a table that has all the values for months.  Then, you can do a left-join on the table that gets the totals, and pull out a sum value.